# How to import data from a Lotus private view into Access?

Tags: ms-access, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm experimenting with Lotus private views for the first time and I finally made a private view that (more or less) has the data I want.  I just need to get it into MS Access.

If this was a standard shared view, I'd just fire up the ODBC administrator, and make a DSN to the database using the NotesSQL driver. Been there, done that.  But you can't get to private views that way.  So, how do I import the data from my private view into Access?

(Also, I'm not one of the IT gurus in our company, so I can't just make a view and share it, even if it's hidden)

Comment: What do you want to do with it? Do you want to display its data, or operate on its data? If the former, I don't see a workaround. If the latter, you can use a passthrough, which will be handled server-side, where, presumably, the private view will be accessible.

Comment: Hello again, David. At your suggestion, I've set up a passthrough, but what is the exact name of my private view? If it is "MyView", do I use "Select * from _MyView_;"?

Comment: I can't help you there. Theoretically, whatever SQL you'd use server-side would be the same SQL you'd put in the passthrough. I know zilch about Lotus Notes so can't even begin to suggest a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is just a one-time import, you can just open the view, select all the documents, and then click Edit > Copy Selected As Table.  Then paste the contents into an Excel Spreadsheet and import that spreadsheet into Access.

If you're looking to have a constant connection from Access to data in Notes, you'll want to change the view to a public view.  In that case, see if one of the IT gurus can help :)

Comment: This will need to be a constant connection. I'm also exploring the existing public views to see if any of them fit my needs. If not, I'll have to get approval from about 5 people to get a new view.

Comment: I agree.  I couldn't find any other way to automatically get the data from a private view into Access. Green check to you.